# while re-training a pre-trained model, I'm facing this issue RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn

model summary:

[image]
[image]
[image]

RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.

It says that the model needs to be compiled. But as far i know, if i compile a model, all the previous trained data will be lost, and the model will be trained from scratch. I don't want this to happen because i want to use this model for further re-training purposes. Can you help me in this.

Can I re-train the model without compiling it and ,save it and use this model for future training ?

Comment: Can you please share the code in code snippets so that we can better assist you on your quuestion?

Answer (score 0):

There 2 techniques while using the pre-train model

**1. Transfer learning:** In the case of transfer learning, we use the pre-train model to train on new kind of dataset so generally, remove the last layer and add a new layer into the network. At this point, as you are adding a new layer the model should be compiled. But don't worry if you are compiling it then weights will not be lost.

**2. Retraining (I guess this is your case):** As you are not modifying the architecture but just training it on additional dataset then also it is not going to loose weights.

Comment: Thanks, i have one more question.
I just want to get the class names of the predictions. I can get the class names on the images that i trained the model. But if i predict an image (say which is not re-trained  but already present in pre-trained model i cannot get its class name).
Is there any way to get the get the class name ??

Comment: Yes, Only if you have access to their JSON file which contains a number to class mapping like in the case of model which are trained on imagenet dataset. Check imagenet json

https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/imagenet_class_index.json


If you find the above answer useful kindly marked it as answered